# Can configure Git to always merge changes to a file in one branch to different files in another?

Tags: git, ghost

I'm maintaining a customized version of a Ghost theme on GitHub. it's taking in a regular stream of changes from the main TryGhost/Casper repo which isn't too hard to keep track of.

There is one thing that's bothering me and that has to do with the `custom-*.hbs` files in my theme. Whenever Ghost updates the `post.hbs`, I must remember to merge those changes into each `custom-*.hbs` template as well.

Is there a way I can tell Git that `post.hbs`'s changes must always be merged into multiple files on my end?

- `post.hbs` -> `post.hbs`
- `post.hbs` -> `custom-blogger.hbs`
- `page.hbs` -> `page.hbs`
- `page.hbs` -> `custom-training.hbs`
- etc

The repo, as it is currently, can be found here:

- https://github.com/jessehouwing/jessehouwingnl-Casper/tree/customized

For now, I've resorted to manually diffing the changes and applying them to the related files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is *no*, which is a bit unfortunate.

When Git is doing a true merge—a "merge as a verb", as I like to call it—Git works with three commits: the *merge base*, which Git finds on its own, and two *tip commits*.  One of the tip commits is always `HEAD`, by definition, and the other is usually identified by some branch name:

```
          o--o--X   <-- you-are-here (HEAD)
         /
...--o--*   [merge base]
         \
          o--o--Y   <-- other-branch
```

All three commits are snapshots of all files, as usual.  Git performs the merge—combines the different changes *since* the merge base—by, in effect, running:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-*> <hash-of-X>   # what we changed
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-*> <hash-of-Y>   # what they changed
```

Git then combs through these differences—the change-sets produced by the two diff commands—and *pairs up* files, so that it knows that `file.ext` in the base is the same file as `file.ext` in ours and/or in theirs.

If the rename-detector detects that `file.ext` in the base has become `newname.ext` in our commit `X`, Git knows that it should combine the changes they made to `file.ext` to the changes we made to `newname.ext`-vs-`file.ext`, storing the final result in `newname.ext`.  But this is strictly pairwise.  Although `git diff` supports several "find copies" options, there is no "find copies" option to `git merge`.  Furthermore, there is no "break existing pairing" option (`git diff` has one, `-B` with a threshold, similar to `-M` for rename-finding and `-C` for copy-finding): if the merge base and one tip contains a file whose path is *P*, that file-pair is paired for the duration of the merge.  If the merge base and the other tip contains a file whose path is *P*, that file-pair is likewise paired.

Hence, if your merge base contains `post.hbs` *and* both tips contain `post.hbs`, the pairing is strictly `post.hbs = post.hbs`.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No. But you can use [`git-merge-file`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-file) to achieve something like this:

`git merge-file <current-version> <common-ancestor> <other-version>`

You can use a third placeholder file to create a "`common-ancestor`", that should contain the pre-merge main file:

`git show HEAD~1:post.hbs > parent-post.hbs`

Then running the following will make a 3-way merge:

`git merge-file custom-post.hbs parent-post.hbs post.hbs`

In order to automatize it you would need to do create a [`post-merge githook`](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post_merge) that runs after the regular merge that recreates the `common-ancestor` file and then merges the changes.

If the `custom-*` files are identical to their non-custom counterpart, consider using [`symlinks`](https://kb.iu.edu/d/abbe).

Comment: Na, they're different, that's their whole purpose. But most of the time the changes are isolated.